# List liked items of user who I follow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two functionalities:
1. to like pins
2. to follow users

Now I want to list pins that are liked by users that I follow.

I have a method in my users controller to list the pins that an user that I am following has **created** :

```
def feeds
        @pins =  Pin.where(user_id: current_user.followings.pluck(:id))
end
```

Now I want to create a list of pins that a user that I follow **has liked**. I am using the acts as votable gem to like pins, so my pins controller has:

```
def like
    @pin.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You have added this restaurant to your favorite list.'
    ModelMailer.new_like_notification(@pin).deliver
  end

  def unlike
    @pin.unliked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You have removed this restaurant from your favorite list.'
  end
```

And to list the pins **the current user** has liked by themself, I have created:

```
def my_favorites
    @pins = current_user.find_liked_items
  end
```

My like table in the db (generated by the acts as votable gem):

```
create_table "likes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "liker_type"
    t.integer  "liker_id"
    t.string   "likeable_type"
    t.integer  "likeable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "likes", ["likeable_id", "likeable_type"], name: "fk_likeables"
  add_index "likes", ["liker_id", "liker_type"], name: "fk_likes"
```

And my follows table:

```
create_table "follows", force: true do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.integer  "followable_id"
        t.string   "followable_type"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

  add_index "follows", ["followable_id", "followable_type"], name: "index_follows_on_followable_id_and_followable_type"
  add_index "follows", ["user_id", "followable_id", "followable_type"], name: "index_follows_on_user_id_and_followable_id_and_followable_type", unique: true
```

And my pin model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
end
```

So I can create a list of pins from the users I am following, or a list of pins that I have liked. Now, I want to list the pins that the users that I follow have liked. Does anyone knows how to do this?

---

I have tried to add this to my controller

```
def feeds 
  @pins = Like.where(liker: current_user.followings.pluck(:id)) 
end
```

but I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: likes.liker: SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."liker" IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: How is the like represented in the db? What method do you call on user to get are their liked pins?

Comment: The gem generated the db table for me (see my post edit). Also I have added acts as votable to my pin model (see post edit).

Comment: What does your followings table look like?

Comment: I have added the follows table as well

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
def feeds 
  @pins = Like.where(liker: current_user.followings) 
end
```